# I try to test signup functionality of https://demo.guru99.com/test/newtours/register.php

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I can fill in the data but I can not submit because I have an overlay for cookies that I can't accept.

> element click intercepted: Element <input name="submit" type="submit" src="images/submit.gif" width="60" height="23" border="0"> is not clickable at point (394, 627). Other element would receive the click: <iframe src="https://cmp-consent-tool.privacymanager.io/latest/index.html#/notice?theme=defaultTheme&useSystemFonts=false&cmpType=tcf" id="gdpr-consent-notice" class="faktor-iframe-wrapper" aria-label="Privacy Manager window" role="dialog" aria-modal="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" style="width: 100%; left: 0px; bottom: 0px; position: fixed; z-index: 2147483647; box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 0px 6px 30px 5px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14) 0px 16px 24px 2px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0px 8px 10px -5px; height: 317px;" cd_frame_id_="41e0d82a904b7400631e7cb189f47523">

I tried to switch to frame, iframe and click accept all, in so many ways as:

```
WebElement iframe = driver.findElement(By.id("gdpr-consent-notice"));
driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);
```

and

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='save']//div[@class='action-wrapper']")).click();
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

I also tried with frame id 0 or 1, with CSS selector for button, and many other combinations I can't even remember. If you can check a solution on the link it would be wonderful.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem is that you are trying to click the wrong button? There is no element on the page with an ID of "save". There's also no BUTTON element on the page. The SUBMIT button HTML is

```
<input name="submit" type="submit" src="images/submit.gif" ...>
```

You can use a simple CSS selector to locate it,

```
input[name='submit']
```

There is no IFRAME around the SUBMIT button element so you don't need to switch into an IFRAME, etc.

Working code is below,

```
driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get('https://demo.guru99.com/test/newtours/register.php');

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name='submit']")).click();
```

Comment: It still doesn't work because every time when my test launches the browser the Privacy Policy would pop up and intercept the click on submit. If you just click submit without filling other data, sometimes driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name='submit']")).click(); is working because the pop up is coming 1 or 2 seconds after but if you also fill the data name, firstN etc, it comes up before submit is clicked.

Comment: the button with id "save" I was trying is the one for the overlay:

Comment: I don't know why but I'm never getting the privacy policy popup that you are referring to. I launched my script with a breakpoint on the last line so the form wouldn't be submitted and just waited. I've now waited over a minute and there's no popup.

Comment: I just deleted all cookies from the site as well and I'm still not seeing the popup. It shouldn't matter for a default Selenium script because the browser is launched with a blank profile but I did it just in case...

Comment: Maybe you interacted with the site some other time? Or you block them somehow?
Do you have the buton like a fingerprint on the right botom of the page(it is called manage privacy setting)? can you click it and see the pop up?

Comment: I mentioned above that I cleared all cookies related to the site so that shouldn't be the issue. I don't have a fingerprint button on the page. Are you sure you gave the right URL? Are there any other steps before the popup like logging in, etc.? Have you tried clearing your cookies for the site? Maybe you are in some strange state.

Comment: Actually, the way I remember, it didn't popup didn't use to happen at the start but after some tests with the functionality and creation of more users, because it can be done with all fields empty idk what happened and eventually it came up and I can not get past it using all kind of identifiers. I deleted cookies and privacy options and nothing changed. Also, as you said it should not be an issue as it is blanked browser when testing.